# No output when trying to run a shell command from python

Tags: python, powershell, cmd

I've never created PowerShell script or anything like that so that's why I'm trying to run the command from Python instead since I thought all I have to do is just called it using the `os.popen()` command.

I have over 5000 folders all containing images that I'm going to extract keypoints from using a script that I've downloaded from [github](https://github.com/CMU-Perceptual-Computing-Lab/openpose/tree/v1.7.0).

When I tried running my Python script nothing shows up. There's a window containing the image with the keypoints that is supposed to show up when I run the command but nothing shows up.

I have tried the command in PowerShell on one folder and it works perfectly.

Here's my script:

```
import os
import sys
import time

os.chdir(
    r"C:\Users\Adam\Downloads\openpose-1.7.0-binaries-win64-cpu-python3.7-flir-3d\openpose"
)
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(
    r"C:\Users\Adam\Downloads\LIP_MPV_256_192\MPV_256_192\all\all\images\train"
):
    for d in dirs:
        print("got here")
        os.popen(
            "bin\\OpenPoseDemo.exe --image_dir"
            + " C:\\Users\\Adam\\Downloads\\LIP_MPV_256_192\\MPV_256_192\\all\\all\\images\\train\\"
            + d
            + "--write_json"
            + " C:\\Users\\Adam\\Downloads\\LIP_MPV_256_192\\MPV_256_192\\all\\all\\images\\pose_coco\\train\\"
            + d
        )
        time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: The `os.chdir()` seems dubious; does the binary not work if you are not in that directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try with [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module from the Python standard library:

```py
import os
import subprocess
import time

os.chdir(
    r"C:\Users\Adam\Downloads\openpose-1.7.0-binaries-win64-cpu-python3.7-flir-3d\openpose"
)
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(
    r"C:\Users\Adam\Downloads\LIP_MPV_256_192\MPV_256_192\all\all\images\train"
):
    for d in dirs:
        print("got here")
        command = [
            "bin\\OpenPoseDemo.exe",
            "--image_dir",
            " C:\\Users\\Adam\\Downloads\\LIP_MPV_256_192\\MPV_256_192\\all\\all\\images\\train\\" + d,
            "--write_json",
            " C:\\Users\\Adam\\Downloads\\LIP_MPV_256_192\\MPV_256_192\\all\\all\\images\\pose_coco\\train\\"
            + d
        ]
        subprocess.run(args=command, shell=False, capture_output=True)
        time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: With `shell=False` the command should be a list, not a string. Windows is less sensitive to this, but breaking up the command line to a list of tokens is also less error-prone.

Comment: `subprocess.run` is definitely the way to go, though perhaps it could be mentioned that `os.popen()` is (now) just an alias for `subprocess.Popen()`. Using the higher-level `run()` function is absolutely recommended, unless you need behavior which `run` cannot accommodate, such as parallel processing (and then you need to do a fair bit of additional housekeeping around the subprocess which `run` takes care of for you).

Comment: @triplee Indeed, I have corrected my answer. Also, thank you for these clarifications and additional information.